# Guice inject based on annotation value

Tags: java, annotations, guice, inject

I would like to use goolge/guice inject a value based on a class i provide with the annotation.

AutoConfig annotation

```
@BindingAnnotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD })
public @interface AutoConfig {
    // default null not possible
    Class<? extends Provider<? extends ConfigLoader<?>>> provider() default XMLAutoConfigProvider.class;
}
```

This is my annotation which allows configuring the type of config, that should be used for the annotated fields.

Usecase:

```
@AutoConfig()
ConfigLoader<?> defaultConfig;

@AutoConfig(provider = JsonConfigProvider)
ConfigLoader<?> jsonConfig;
```

I want to have two configs, one default/xml one and a json one. They will probably never occur in the same class at the same time. But i don't know when the one or the other is used. I used the approach with a class because they are provided by some dependencies/libs and this annotation will be used for some (plugable) submodules.

MyGuiceModule

```
public class MyGuiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(new TypeLiteral<ConfigLoader<?>>() {})
            .annotatedWith(AutoConfig.class)
            .toProvider(autoConfig.provider());
    }
}
```

This the critical part, i just cannot imagine how to implement it.

So basically i just want to use the provider class specified in the annotation.
Its not necessary to use the provider class here too. Because autoConfig.provider().newInstance() is basically all i need. (I need to use a setter on the new instance but thats all i want to do at this place)

To sum it up all i really want to do is push the annotation (or its values to the provider) either using the get(AutoConfig autoConfig) or in the constructor. 
Currently i only use the constructor to inject the configFile value i want to set on the newly generated config instance.

Comment: I suppose there is a solution for this problem, but none that I have at hand right now. You could consider if you really need one Qualifier with two possible behaviors or if you just work with a XmlConfig and a JSonConfig annotation and bind explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that `@AutoConfig(provider = JsonConfigProvider) ConfigLoader<?> jsonConfig` is going to return you exactly the results of `jsonConfigProvider.get()`, and JsonConfigProvider obviously has a public parameterless constructor for `newInstance` to work, why wouldn't you just ask for a `JsonConfigProvider` in the first place?

Fundamentally Guice is just a `Map<Key, Provider>` with fancy wrapping. The bad news is that this makes variable bindings like "bind `Foo<T>` for all T" impossible to express concisely, and that includes your "bind `@Annotation(T) Foo` for all T". The good news is that you still have two options.

### Bind each provider separately

Though you can't inspect annotations during provision (or tell Guice to do so for you), Guice will compare annotations using their `equals` methods if you bind an annotation *instance* rather than an annotation *class* (the way you would with `Names.named("some-name")`). This means that you can bind a `ConfigLoader<?>` with each expected annotation in a Module. Of course, this also means you'll have to have a list of possible ConfigLoader Providers available at configuration time, but they have to be compile-time constants anyway if you're using them as annotation parameters.

This solution works with constructor injection as well, but for fields you'll need both `@Inject` and `@AutoConfig(...)`, and AutoConfig will need to keep its `@BindingAnnotation` meta-annotation.

To do this, you're going to have to write an implementation of your annotation, the way Guice does with [`NamedImpl`](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/name/NamedImpl.java). Note that the implementations of `equals` and `hashCode` must match the ones Java provides in `java.lang.Annotation`. Then it's just a matter of (redundantly) binding like this:

```
for(Class<ConfigLoader<?>> clazz : loaders) {
  bind(ConfigLoader.class).annotatedWith(new AutoConfigImpl(clazz))
      .toProvider(clazz);
}
```

The definition of `equals` is up to you, which means you can (and should) bind `@AutoConfig(ConfigEnum.JSON)` and keep the Guice bindings in your modules rather than specifying your requested implementation all over your codebase.

### Use custom injections

You can also use [custom injections](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections) to search your injected types for custom annotations like `@AutoConfig`. At this point, you'd be *using Guice as a platform* to interpret `@AutoConfig` *instead of* `@Inject`, which means that constructor injection won't work but that you can control your injection based on the injected instance, field name, field annotation, annotation parameters, or any combination thereof. If you choose this style, you can drop `@BindingAnnotation` from AutoConfig.

Use the example in [the wiki article linked above](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections) as your template, but at minimum you'll need to:

1. Use `bindListener` on Binder or AbstractModule to match types that need this custom injection.
2. In the TypeListener you bind, search injected types for `@AutoConfig`-annotated fields, and if they have any matching methods then bind those matching methods to a MembersInjector or InjectionListener. You'll probably want to tease the class literal out of the annotation instance here, and pass in the Field and Class as constructor arguments to the MembersInjector/InjectionListener.
3. In the MembersInjector or InjectionListener you write, instantiate the provider and set the field to the instance the provider provides.

This is a very powerful feature, which would futher allow you to--for instance--automatically provide the configuration based on which instance you're injecting into or based on the name of the field. However, use it carefully and document it heavily, because it may be counter-intuitive to your coworkers that Guice is providing for an annotation other than `@Inject`. Also bear in mind that this won't work for constructor injection, so refactoring from field injection to constructor injection will cause Guice to complain that it's missing a required binding to instantiate the class.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to use a custom annotation that receives a enum param to choose the implementation. After a lot of research, debug and testing, I came to the following solution:

```
//enum to define authentication types
public enum AuthType {
    Ldap, Saml
}

//custom annotation to be used in injection
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD })
@BindingAnnotation
public @interface Auth {
    AuthType value();
}

//defintion of authenticator
public interface Authenticator {
    public void doSomehting();
}


//Authenticator implementations 
public class LdapAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

    @Override
    public void doSomehting() {
        // doing ldap stuff
    }

}

public class SamlAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

    @Override
    public void doSomehting() {
        // doing saml stuff
    }

}

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    // annotate fields to bind to implementations
    private @Auth(AuthType.Ldap) Authenticator ldap;
    private @Auth(AuthType.Saml) Authenticator saml;

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        //bind the implementation to the annotation from field
        bindAnnotated("ldap", LdapAuthenticator.class);
        bindAnnotated("saml", SamlAuthenticator.class);

    }

    private void bindAnnotated(String fieldName, Class<? extends Authenticator> implementation) {
        try {
            //get the annotation from fields, then bind it to implementation                
            Annotation ann = MyModule.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName).getAnnotation(Auth.class);
            bind(Authenticator.class).annotatedWith(ann).to(implementation);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}


//usage:  add @Auth(<AuthType>) to the dependency

public class ClientClass {

    private Authenticator authenticator;

    @Inject
    public ClientClass(@Auth(AuthType.Ldap) Authenticator authenticator) {
        this.authenticator = authenticator;
    }
}
```

Check the documentation of [Binder](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/Binder.html)

I tested the Jeff Bowman solution, but it apparently works only binding to providers

Answer (score 0):

As a [BindingAnnotations#binding-annotations-with-attributes](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations#binding-annotations-with-attributes) states equals() and hashCode() should be properly implemented. So given that there is MyAnnotation

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    SomeEnum value() default SomeEnum.A;
}
```

which is used to specify SomeInterface implementation(SomeDefault and SomeOther), SomeModule class could look like

```
public class SomeModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Key.get(SomeInterface.class, createAnnotationClass(A))).to(SomeDefault.class);
        // more common binding expresion
        bind(SomeInterface.class).annotatedWith(createAnnotationClass(B)).to(SomeDefault.class);
    }

    private Annotation createAnnotationClass(SomeEnum someEnum) {
        return new MyAnnotation() {
            @Override
            public SomeEnum value() {
                return someEnum;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                return MyAnnotation.class;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object o) {
                if (this == o) return true;
                if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
                MyAnnotationCl myAnnoCl = (MyAnnotationCl) o;
                return A == myAnnoCl.getValue();
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                // from java annotation documentation
                return (127 * "value".hashCode()) ^ value().hashCode();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then annotation could be used as follows:

```
public class DoSomethingWithSomething {
    private final SomeInterface someImplementation;

    @Inject
    public DoSomethingWithSomething(
            @MyAnnotation SomeInterface someDefault
//            @MyAnnotation(A) SomeInterface someDefault
//            @MyAnnotation(B) SomeInterface someOther
    ) {

        this.someImplementation = someDefault;
    }
}
```