# Guice inject annotation value

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Hello i want to inject annotation value to parameter. for example

```
@BindingAnnotation
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    int value() default 0;
}

public class A {
    @Inject @MyAnnotation(30)
    protected Integer a;
}
```

how i can inject 30 inside the `a` variable.

thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guice inject based on annotation value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549549/guice-inject-based-on-annotation-value)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`bindConstant()`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/AbstractModule.html#bindConstant()) as

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class).to(30);
```

You can just have `@Inject and @MyAnnotation` annotated on your integer field.

---

**Note:**
In case your `MyAnnotation` annotation has one more element say `stringValue()` like,

```
@BindingAnnotation
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    int value() default 0;
    String stringValue default "";
}
```

adding one more binding for that element `bindConstant().annotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class).to("someValue")` seems to work in the following case, but I feel this is not the correct approach.

```
public class A {
    @Inject
    public A(@MyAnnotation Integer integer, @MyAnnotation String string) {
      //Here integer will be 10 and string will be someValue
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when user use annotation to another field called     
`@Inject @MyAnnotation(20) protected Integer b;    @Inject @MyAnnotation(2) protected Integer c;`

Comment: @Shay_t I don't get you. The bindings here *seems* to happen by type (as you can see from my second code, it has one String and one Integer)

Comment: you are binding a specific value "bindConstant().annotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class).to("someValue") " i want to bind the annotation value, when using the annotation.

"@MyAnnotation(stringValue="hello there i am the value that will be assign to the str variable")
String str;"