# Inject parameter only when it's useful, otherwise default

Tags: java, guice

I couldn't find a satisfying answer to this anywhere, links are appreciated.

In Guice, suppose I create a `Frobnifier` that takes an integer parameter `velocity` that tells it how fast to frobnify things:

```
public class Frobnifier {
  @Inject
  public Frobnifier(@FrobnificationSpeed Integer velocity) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Now suppose I'd like this value to be 5 by default, but I'd also like to enable clients to override this value at injection time if they feel like it should be something else.

What is the Guice best practice here? Should I create a module for this class and install it in other modules?

Comment: Provide a default value for FrobnificationSpeed annotation?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Can you show you FrobnificationSpeed interface?

Comment: `public @interface FrobnificationSpeed {  }`

Comment: Have a look at one of my answers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49010954/guice-inject-annotation-value/49013060#49013060. But I'm not sure if it is the best way though

Comment: Ideally It'd be best if Frobnifier clients didn't have to specify the speed, but could if they so wished

Comment: So, what if you have an element in the `FrobnificationSpeed` like `int speed() default 5;`?

Comment: https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.2/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/OptionalBinder.html